# How much money do I lose when I die?

Tags: dead-island

In Dead Island, it notifies you that you lost a certain amount of money when you die. How much is lost exactly?

Comment: I'd like to know why people down voted this. It seems like a legitimate question to me.

Comment: Did people down vote because NiteCyper answered their own question? Doing such a thing is encouraged! http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but I feel that the OP should at least give somebody else a chance to answer first and secondly documentation is more useful when the issue at hand is not easy to figure out at the first glance.

Comment: Many of my questions that I answer myself, I leave unaccepted to give others the opportunity to one-up my answers. Secondly, I'm often providing video documentation now, but was too lazy for this one. I think that a bigger issue here is, the better thing to do is copy Jarrod's answer, for example, and then add video evidence to it, but it feels like stealing. Is this proper etiquette?

Comment: @NiteCyper That's a good topic to bring up in [meta] (but search for previous discussion about it first). You might also want to see [this related meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5679/4797), too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cash penalty for death is 10% of total money, however, if you're playing as Xian Mei, this can be lessened (by up to -45%) with the [life insurance](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Xian_Mei_Skill_Trees#Survival_Tree) skill.

---

**Source:** Modified the `C:/.../Steam/steamapps/common/dead island/DI/Data0.pak/Skills` file and tested the `<prop n="PenaltyOnDeath" v="1"/>` value; `v="2"` increases it to 20%, whereas `v="0"` removes the penalty.

Answer (score 2):

In Dead Island, when you die, you lose 10% of your money.